# gmail html preview removes css rule with page-break property

Tags: html, css, gmail, rules, page-break

we are sending html page as attachment to our users which they can use to print. When you view the html page using gmail in browser it removes any css rule with page-break-after property.

We want to force page-break for printing.

What is the work around for this.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing you can do about it. As explained by chipcullen Gmail strips out all CSS in webpage except the one inside the HTML tags, and even with those it does strange stuff like removing the `page-break-after` attributes.

The **only workaround** I can think about is to **keep the html file or your server and simply send a link** to it in your mail message in place of the attachement.

*Great is the mistery surrounding these type of decisions made by Google engineers.
Maybe they want users to go back using Outlook. Well, they almost convinced me.*

Answer (score 1):

I can't say about the page-break-after property specifically, but I *do* know that Gmail does WEIRD things to CSS in HTML emails. For instance, Gmail will strip out *any* CSS that is either in the `<head>` or inline with the `<body>` tag. You will have to apply your rule inline.

From what it sounds like, you're relying more on the browser to render the attachment, and the user is printing from there. Are you sure page-break-after is supported in your test browser?

Comment: Yes, when you download the html page and preview in any browser, it shows the page-break-after property. It forces a page break when you print the page. The problem is only when you preview the attachment(html) using gmail. Gmail opens the attachment in https://mail-attachment.googleusercontent.com/attachment/?ui..... and removes any style with this property

Comment: Thanks Chip Cullen,

I have tried to explain the problem in detail here http://www.campaignmonitor.com/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=24398#p24398